# Scheme in Xcode 4 that builds an external project when I run another

Tags: xcode, building

I have two projects that use shared source files. How can I organize the building process so that when I run one of the projects, Xcode builds both of them, making sure that both projects can still compile with the changes in the shared files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change Schemes for both projects, going to Build section there and adding projects, so that Build section for each project's Scheme has both projects.